# Awk - How to cut a line, check if a column matches something, print another column?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a *laaaaaarge* file like this:

```
VENDOR|QTY|ITEM|PRICE
2|3|Sugar|15
3|3|Coffee|35
4|244|Sugar2|55
33|2|Pizza|36
3|3|Pizza|55
5|5|Pizza2|33
6|6|Pizza3|44
```

How do I print `VENDOR` and `PRICE` **IFF** `ITEM` is `Pizza`?

I've tried `grep` but it's slow.

I could write a python code like so,

```
for line in file:
    fields = line.split('|')
    if fields[2] == 'Pizza':
        print fields[0], fields[-1]
```

but I want to do it in *Awk* from the shell itself. How do I do this?

**Update**

How do I check substrings as well?

I want to output `VENDOR` and `PRICE` if *Pizza* occurs in `ITEM`?

Output should be:

```
33|36
3|55
5|33
6|44
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This makes it:

```
$ awk -F\| '$3=="Pizza" {print $1,$4}' file
33 36
3 55
```

#### Explanation

- `-F\|` set `|` as field delimiter.
- `$3=="Pizza"` check if the 3rd field is "Pizza".
- `{print $1,$4}` prints the 1st and 4th fields.

---

### Update

> I want to output `VENDOR` and `PRICE` if *Pizza* occurs in `ITEM`?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} $3~/Pizza/ {print $1,$4}' file
33|36
3|55
5|33
6|44
```

#### Explanation

- `$3~/Pizza/` checks "occurs", as well as `$3=="Pizza` checks exact matching.
- `BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}` sets the (input & output) field separator to be `|`.

Comment: Will Accept in 11 minutes :)

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to do as well? Because I'm looking for speed too :)

Comment: I think this is very efficient. Anyway, some gurus may come with better solutions, maybe in `sed`. Then you can compare their efficiency using `time` in front of the command.

Comment: Note I updated my answer so that the output is written with `|`, I had missed that part of your update :)